# How can i use enums to set priority in an arraylist?

Tags: java, arraylist, enums

I'm writing a program using two classes. I have to prompt user to add an item as a string, set the priority as low/high/medium, and get the date. All these are ToDoItem objects that are stored in an ArrayList called toDoItems. Depending on the priority that the user has inputted, each ToDoItem object holding the item, priority, and date should sort itself out.

For example:

```
Add item: Run
Set due date: 11/27/2015
Enter priority: High

Print All items:
0. Run -1- (11/27/1993)

Add item: Jump
Set due date: 11/28/1993
Enter priority: Low

Print All items:
0. Run -1- (11/27/1993)
1. Jump -2- (11/27/1993)

Add item: Walk
Set due date: 11/19/1993
Enter priority: Medium 

Print All items:
0. Run -1- (11/27/1993)
1. Walk -2- (11/19/1993)
2. Jump -3- (11/27/1993)
```

At some point i have to be able to delete a ToDoItem object from the arrayList according to it's index which i wrote:

```
 public static void deleteToDoItem() {
      System.out.print("Enter index of item to delete: ");
      int delete = k.nextInt();
      toDoItems.remove(i);  
   }
```

Which gives me an error of

```
 ----jGRASP exec: javac -g MyList.java

MyList.java:75: error: class, interface, or enum expected
   public static void deleteToDoItem() {
                 ^
MyList.java:83: error: class, interface, or enum expected
         int delete = k.nextInt();
         ^
MyList.java:84: error: class, interface, or enum expected
         toDoItems.remove(i);  
         ^
MyList.java:85: error: class, interface, or enum expected
   } 
   ^
4 errors

 ----jGRASP wedge2: exit code for process is 1.
 ----jGRASP: operation complete.
```

I got all the objects down and both my classes are working but i'm stuck on how to write my priority enum. I know at some point i have to:

write an enumerated type that represents priority high, medium, and low.

Change the priority field of this object to use this newly defined enumerated type.

& write a single method that now only accepts the newly defined enumerated type.

**UPDATE** //Sharing full code
ToDoItem class:

```
import java.text.*;
import java.util.Date;
import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.*;

public class ToDoItem {

   private String description;
   private static Date dueDate;
   private Priority priority;

   private static DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy");

   public ToDoItem() {
   }
   public ToDoItem(String desc) {
      description = desc;
      dueDate = null;
      priority = priority.HIGH;
   }
   public ToDoItem(String desccription, String d) throws ParseException{
      this.description = description;
      dueDate = df.parse(d);
   }
   public ToDoItem(String description, String p, String d) throws ParseException{
      this.description = description;
      this.priority = Priority.valueOf(p.toUpperCase());
      dueDate = df.parse(d);
   }   
   public String toString() {
      return description + " -"+priority+"- " + df.format(dueDate);
   }

   public static void setDueDate(String s) {
      try {
         dueDate = df.parse(s);
      } catch(Exception ex) {
         System.out.println(ex);
      }      
   }
   public String getDescription() {
      return description;
   }     
   public String getDueDate() {
      return df.format(dueDate);
   }   
}
```

MyList class:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.io.*;
import java.text.*;

public class MyList {


       public static ArrayList<ToDoItem> toDoItems = new ArrayList<>();
       private static Scanner k = new Scanner(System.in);

       public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException {

          while(true) {
             printMenu();
             processInput();
          } 
       }

       public static void printMenu() {
          System.out.println("[a]dd an item"); 
          System.out.println("[d]elete an item");
          System.out.println("[t]oggle complete");  
          System.out.println("[p]rint all");  
          System.out.println("[q]uit"); 
       }

       private static void processInput() throws ParseException {
          Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
          String input = s.next();

          if(input.equals("a")) {
             addToDoItem();
          }   
          else if(input.equals("d")) {
             deleteToDoItem();
          }
          else if(input.equals("t")) {
            // toggleComplete();
          }      
          else if(input.equals("p")) {
             printAll();
          }
          else if(input.equals("q")) {
             System.exit(0);
          }      
       }

       private static void addToDoItem() throws ParseException {

          System.out.print("Enter an item to add to list: ");
          String desc = k.nextLine();

          System.out.print("Enter Date (MM/dd/YYYY): ");
          String dueDate = k.nextLine();
          ToDoItem.setDueDate(dueDate);

          System.out.print("Enter priority (Low/Medium/High): ");
          String prior = k.nextLine();
          //int p = Integer.parseInt(prior);

          toDoItems.add(new ToDoItem(desc, prior, dueDate));
       }

       public static void printAll() {  
          //System.out.print(toDoItems.size() + ". ");
          for (int index = 0; index < toDoItems.size(); index++)
             System.out.println(index + ". " + toDoItems.get(index));
          }  

       public static void deleteToDoItem() {
          int index = 0;
          System.out.print("Enter index of item to delete: ");
          int delete = k.nextInt();
          toDoItems.remove(index);  
       } 

      // public static void toggleComplete() {
          ///// 
      // }  
    }
```

Comment: share your full code ?

Comment: You can implement a Comparator for your list and order it accordingly. See it here: http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-collections/sorting.html

Comment: @Soorapadman I have posted above

Comment: You should definitely read about static. All your TodoItem instances share the same description, dueDate and priority.

Comment: @JorgeCampos But I must use enum in my code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The compilation error which you are getting, that is because of the improper closing brackets for class. Remove the closing bracket after the `printAll` method and add it after the `deleteToDoItem` method. That will solve your compilation issue.

The last part of the code, it should be like this:

```
  private static void printAll() {
    for (int index = 0; index < toDoItems.size(); index++)
      System.out.println(toDoItems.get(index));
  }

// Extra bracket is removed from here.

  public static void deleteToDoItem() {
    System.out.print("Enter index of item to delete: ");
    int delete = k.nextInt();
    toDoItems.remove(i);
  }
} // put it here.
```

The variable `i` is also undefined in the `deleteToDoItem` method.

You can define the `Priority` `enum`. Make use of the `getValue()` method for fetching the `int` values of the `Priority`.

```
enum Priority {
  HIGH(1), LOW(3), MEDIUM(2);
  private int value;
  Priority (int value) {
    this.value = value;
  }
  public int getValue() {
    return value;
  }
}
```

The the `ToDoItem` class will look like this:

**Note:** It will expect Priority as `String` like (`high`, `low` or `medium`) instead of integer. Also now all the members of the class are instance variable not the class variable. They now belong to individual object of the ToDoItem class.

```
public class ToDoItem {

  private  String description;
  private  Date dueDate;
  private  Priority priority;

  private static DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy");

  public ToDoItem() {
  }

  public ToDoItem(String desc) {
    description = desc;
    dueDate = null;
    priority = Priority.HIGH;
  }
  public ToDoItem(String desccription, String d) throws ParseException{
    this.description = description;
    dueDate = df.parse(d);
  }
  public ToDoItem(String description, String p, String d) throws ParseException{
    this.description = description;
    this.priority = Priority.valueOf(p.toUpperCase());
    dueDate = df.parse(d);
  }
  public String toString() {
    return description + " -"+priority+"- " + df.format(dueDate);
  }

  public void setDueDate(String s) {
    try {
      dueDate = df.parse(s);
    } catch(Exception ex) {
      System.out.println(ex);
    }
  }
  public String getDescription() {
    return description;
  }
  public String getDueDate() {
    return df.format(dueDate);
  }
}
```

You can avoid this integer conversion in the `MyList` class, enter the `Priority` as (`high`, `low` or `medium`), and pass it directly to the `ToDoItem` class constructors.

```
int p = Integer.parseInt(prior);  // not required.
```

To print the data in sorted manner you need to implement a custom `Comparator`. Here is the code which uses the custom `Comparator` based on the `Priority` of the `ToDoItem` object.

```
public static void printAll() {
  Collections.sort(toDoItems, new Comparator<ToDoItem>() {
    @Override
    public int compare(ToDoItem o1, ToDoItem o2) {
      return o1.getPriority().getValue() - o2.getPriority().getValue();
    }
  });
  //System.out.print(toDoItems.size() + ". ");
  for (int index = 0; index < toDoItems.size(); index++)
    System.out.println(index + ". " + toDoItems.get(index));
}
```

Also get the getter into the `ToDoItem` class for `Priority`:

```
public Priority getPriority() {
  return priority;
}
```

Comment: But i still do not know how to get the priority enum

Comment: @pyuntae I have added some fixes to your code. Do check.

Comment: Got it. How do I get the priority to print out the number instead of the words LOW/HIGH/MEDIUM i want it to print like the number according to the priority that has been set and the array index to move according to the priority

Comment: Not sure if it's because i put the enum code in the ToDoItem class or not but it keeps giving me an error that they cant find the symbol for value

Comment: @pyuntae Keep the `Priority` enum code outside of the `ToDoItem` class. I don't get any error.

Comment: I still get the same error? not sure why... I even made a whole new class for it and still the same thing. Cannot find symbol and points ^ to value in both this.value and return value

Comment: @pyuntae Did you add the `Priority` enum code in the same file as the `ToDoItem.java`. Do that. Just keep it outside of the ToDoItem class.

Comment: Yes i did. still the same thing.

Comment: Cannot find symbol and ^ pointing to value in this.value and return value;

Comment: I added private int value = 0; and now it doesn't give me the message but it still prints out the words LOW/HIGH/MEDIUM instead of the number in the output

Comment: @pyuntae just look at the priority code and make sure you have taken the correct and complete code from the answer.

Comment: @pyuntae `public class Test {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Priority priority = Priority.HIGH;
    System.out.println(priority.getValue());
  }
}
` This is a simple code which prints `1`.

Comment: @pyuntae   this is the right way `this.priority = Priority.valueOf(p.toUpperCase());` and the toString for ToDoItem class is following: `return description + " -"+priority.getValue()+"- " + df.format(dueDate);`

Comment: If i use the example that i gave for the output in my code, when i prompt the program to print all the number for priority prints as 3 instead of 1. `0. Run -1- 11/28/1993
1. Jump -3- 11/28/1993` but it's supposed to print from `-1-` to `-2-` to `-3-` and so on. The only difference is that the whole object moves up or down the arraylist according to the priority that is set. Not sure if i'm explaining it correctly?

Comment: @pyuntae basically you need to sort them by their priority, that is what you mean? High -> Low?

Comment: Yes. High to medium to low.

Comment: @pyuntae check the answer.